Selecting rows in pandas where string word is contain in column
I am new to pandas and having trouble with selecting any of the rows where the column Category contains the string 'Insulated'.
I have tried .str.contains('Insulated') and binned[binned['Category'].isin(['Insulated Down', 'Insulated Synthetic'])]. This comes back with NaN or doesn't selection any rows.
I am not sure want I have done wrong.
Any help is really appreciated, thank you.
Below code is grouping the Bin Location:
binned = bin[~bin['Bin Location'].isin(['WH 2', '*WH3*'])].groupby('Bin Location').agg({'Quantity On Hand' : 'sum', 'Category' : 'unique'}).reset_index().sort_values(by='Quantity On Hand', ascending=False)


I was expecting this to select all Bin locations where the Category contains Insulated Down' and 'Insulated Synthetic'.


I think your dataframe has a list in its columns, therefore you'll need to explode the list first to check each element in the list with .str.  Example... df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[['A', 'B', 'C'],['E', 'F', 'G']]}) input dataframe.  Then try this... df[df.explode('col1')['col1'].str.contains('A').groupby(level=0).any()]

To extend the excellent @Scott Boston approach to deal with your issue of two strings (Insulated Down' and 'Insulated Synthetic') then you could use code along the lines of: df2 = df[df.explode('col1')['col1'].str.contains('A|F').groupby(level=0).any()]] which uses the OR operator.

The values in column 'Category' are lists, so a possible solution is to use apply on axis=1 and check each element in each list:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Quantity": [1, 2], "Category": [["Bikepacking", "Hats"], ["Insulated Down"]]}
)

m = df.apply(lambda x: any("Insulated" in e for e in x["Category"]), axis=1)
out = df[m]

   Quantity          Category
1         2  [Insulated Down]

